# Restrict users to post news feed on team site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using Sharepoint 2013 online team site. On that site I am using Newsfeed webpart.

I want to restrict all the user should not be able to post on news feed of my team site.

How can I do that?

Comment: so you are adding the newsfeed webpart just to show the existing newsfeed and you do not want the users to add any newsfeed from that site

Answer (score 1):

You can add the css into that page and hide the Textbox or the whole div which contains the textbox to post into newsfeed.

Add a new content editor webpart to that page and add below css:

```
#ms-microblogdiv { display:none!important }
```